# Manually changing node position is networkx draw

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I tried manually changing the positions of a graph in `networkx` before drawing, but it seems to have no effect.

Here's an mwe, with this I would expect the two figures to be different, more precisely, for the second be wider horizontally and thus have more space between nodes, but even the node labels seem to share the same relative size:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)
T = nx.relabel_nodes(T, lambda x: str(x))
pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")
plt.figure()
nx.draw(T, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("1.png")
pos = {key: (val[0] * pow(10, 5), val[1]) for key, val in pos.items()}
plt.figure()

nx.draw(T, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("2.png")
```

I guess this is mostly a matplotlib issue, but what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The `x` positions are changing, it's just that since they are scaled with a factor of 10000 from their original positions, the difference is not noticeable unless you show the axis and the ticks.

See code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.subplot(211)
T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)
T = nx.relabel_nodes(T, lambda x: str(x))
pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")
nx.draw(T, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('on')
plt.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)

plt.subplot(212)
pos = {key: (val[0]*pow(10,5), val[1]) for key, val in pos.items()}
nx.draw(T, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('on')
plt.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)
```

[image]